# @Valid and Binding Result for Data from DB

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring validation(JSR 303) in one of the web apps.I have no issues when a user submits data and spring validation works pretty neat.But I have a scenario where I have to fetch data from a service and validate it and then bind them to my view.(something non-form validation).How can  I use @Valid in this case or does it have to be done differently?

Here is a sample code,i started with

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getView(
        @PathVariable("id") final String id, @User user,
        HttpSession session) {

    User user=  getUser();

   BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(user, "user");

   validator.validate(user, result);

   if(result.hasErrors()){
       logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Errors");
   }

  ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView ("home");
  view.addObject("user",user );
  view.addAllObject(result.getModel());

   return view;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to inject default `org.springframework.validation.Validator` into your controller (if `@Valid` works you should be able to do it)

```
@Autowired
Validator validator;
```

run validation manually as follows

```
User user = ...;
BindingResult result = BeanPropertyBindingResult(user, "user");
validator.validate(user, result);
```

and merge results into `ModelMap` (declare it as argument of your method) as follows

```
model.addAllAttributes(result.getModel());
```

Comment: Thanks for the path.I have updated my post to include my changes.I am getting Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/apache/log4j/Level.TRACE.I check my maven dependencies and I am using the same release for all of the Spring jars(3.1.0).Not sure about this error.

Comment: Do you have log4j as one of your dependencies? v1.2.x or higher?

Comment: Sorry,I should have updated my progress here.Yes,I was having slf4j and log4j in my maven.I have to get the later away.Now,I can see the errors from my validator and I have set the bindingresult to my modelAndView but the errors does not reflect in the jsp,I have updated the initail post with the code.

Comment: I passed "Errors" variable and was using user in my jsp.Which was causing the error not binding in my view.I have updated my post.Hope this helps.