# Spring validation prior to submit (Method.GET)

Tags: java, forms, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm experiencing a strange issue with Spring MVC (latest version, 4.0.6).
While trying to validate a form before submitting it I'm able to get validation in place and populate given Spring Form's (truncated for sake of clarity)

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="contratto">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-error" element="div" />
</form:form>
```

[image]

The problem is that Spring **formatters** are not called at all, therefore giving me unlocalized dates and numbers.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{contractId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit_form(@PathVariable("contractId") int id, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    Contratti contratto = ejbRepository.getContratto(id);
    model.addAttribute("contratto", contratto);
    BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(contratto, "contratto");
    new CustomContrattoValidator().validate(contratto, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAllAttributes(result.getModel());
    }
return "contratti/form/edit";
}
```

By using classic approach, like annotating the handler method as stated in [Display JSR-303 errors before form submission with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618408/display-jsr-303-errors-before-form-submission-with-spring-mvc) or [@Valid and Binding Result for Data from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918916/valid-and-binding-result-for-data-from-db)  or [Spring - adding BindingResult to newly created model attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052752/spring-adding-bindingresult-to-newly-created-model-attribute) the issue is even worse, as the

```
new CustomContrattoValidator().validate(contratto, result);
```

seems to report all missing fields (like if the object is completely empty, even if the code is exactly the same and I'm getting it from DB).

I'm completely lost and can't get my head around.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Its a good way to pass @modelAttribute (in a GET method) to binding result with: BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(contratto, "contratto");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the conversion service in the BeanPropertyBindingResult.

Obtain the conversion service:

```
@Autowired private ConversionService conversionService;
```

Pass it along:

```
BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(contratto, "contratto");
result.initConversion(conversionService);
```